# Postgres-xl - InternalServerError: Can not get current value of the sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sequence, internal-server-error

In an working postgres-xl, a table with following sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.t1_id_seq
START WITH -1000000
INCREMENT BY -1
MINVALUE -9223372036854775807
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;
```

after any power outage there is a good chance that insert statement gets this error:

```
InternalServerError
Can not get current value of the sequence
```

If explicitly mention an amount for that column it would be inserted. There is also other tables with sequences with positive start point and increment amount that remain intact after the incident. 
Any help how to prevent this failure, please?